# Finding the angle in a square

Tags: geometry

[image: squareABCD]
Hello, I don't know what to with this problem:
 I have to find angle ABS in given square (image).
Where S is the last important unnamed point in the picture.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Squares have four right angles

Comment: Well, $\angle ABC$ will be $90^{\circ}$. But I don't think that's what you really need?

Comment: Sorry I meant ABS, where S is the last important point in the picture.

Comment: Where is $S$ ??

Comment: Sorry, it is edited now

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your diagram.  I see $1,2,3.$  What are those?  Lengths of $DS, AS, BS$?  And the side of the square is length $a$?

Comment: Yes. It exactly like you wrote.

Comment: Why don't you label point $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the cosine law, it's pretty straightforward:

$$A=\arccos\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$

so

$$\angle ABS=\arccos\frac{a^2+3^2-2^2}{2(a)(3)}$$
$$=\arccos\frac{a^2-5}{6a}$$

Note that $a<3$, otherwise $AS$ and $DS$ would not exist.